# What is the mantra for Putra Kameshti Yagna?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, identification-request, yajna

In 15th chapter of Bala Khanda of Ramayana, before performing Putra Kameshti Yagna, Rishyashringa said :-

> "I will procedurally conduct the ritual contained in the **preamble of atharva-veda with procedural hymns, called putra kaameSTi** i.e., the ritual that bestows sons, for your benefit."

It's very interesting and i wanted to know about the hymn about Putra Kameshti Yagna. So my question is, What is the hymns for Putra Kameshti Yagna, according to Atharva Veda?

Comment: The Putra Kāmeṣṭi Yajña is a Vaidika Yajña of the Atharvaṇa veda, and thus is only open to Yajñopavīta wearers who are adhikārins and have done vedādhyayana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the mantra possibly related to Putra Kameshti Yagna from the 3rd Kanda, Sukta 23 from Atharva Veda.

> Yena vehad babhūvitha nāsayāmasi tattvat
> Idam tadanyatra tvadapa dure ni dadhmasi
>
> Āte yonim garbha etu pumānbāna-ivesudhim
> Ā viro ’tra jayatam putraste dasamasycih
>
> Pumdmsam putrarh janaya tam pumdnanu jayatam
> Bhavasi putranam mata jatanam janayasca yan
>
> Yani bhadrani bijdnyrsabhd janayanti ca
> Taistvcim putram vindasva sd prasurdhenuka bhava
>
> Krnomi te prajapatyama yonim garbha etu te
> Vindasva tvam putram nari yastubhyam samasacchamu tasmai tvam bhava
>
> Yasamm dyauspita prthivi mata samudro mulam virudham babhuva
> Tastvā putravidyaya daivīh pravantvosadhayah

---

The English translation, here:-

> 1. The cause by which you have become infertile, unable to conceive and carry, we remove from you and take it elsewhere far from you.
> 2. Let the living embryo come into your womb and be like an arrow in the quiver, and let the ten month mature bonny brave baby take birth for you here in the home.
> 3. Bear a **brave virile son**, and after that too let **brave virile son** be born. Be a proud mother of the brave, of those that are born and of those you would bear.
> 4. Auspicious are the seeds and vitalities of life which fertility herbs produce. With the use of them increase your fertility and bear a brave child. Such as you are, be a fertile woman and a brave mother.
> 5. O woman, I create fertility and motherly potential for you in your system. Let the living embryo be in your womb. Be blest with a son who may be a boon for peace and joy for you, and for him, you too be the mother of peace and joy for his soul.
> 6. Those herbs of which the sun, the light of heaven, and the self-refulgent Lord Supreme is the father, and the earth is the mother, and the sea and the cosmic ocean is the root, may those divine herbs bless you, protect you and increase your fertility to get brave progeny.